# How to use the replaceAll() method, how can I specify my regex to delete any blackslash and char right after it?

Tags: java, regex

In this string below, I need to remove the backslash and the char immediately after it. Code snippet below

```
String raw;
String s = "###\\A";)
String formatted = raw.replaceAll("\\.?", "");
System.out.println(formatted)
```

when I printed out the formatted, I got ###A instead of ###
it appears that in the regex "\.?" , the ? is not doing its job. I may be missing something here. My goal is to get rid of the // and the A. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Is char any character, or A-Z?

Comment: Delete anything escaped try `"(?s)\\\\."`

Answer (score 1):

Try this REGEX `\\\\[A-Z]?`

```
String s = "###\\ZABCDE";
String formatted = s.replaceAll("\\\\[A-Z]?", "");
System.out.println(formatted);
```

, output

```
###ABCDE
```

[Regex Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: The reason for this is that ```"\\.?"``` becomes ```\.?```, while ```"\\\\.?"``` becomes ```\\.?```. The second regex has escaped the slash, while the first regex has escaped the period.

Comment: @Michael Bianconi, yes char is anything between A-Z

Comment: @Edward :  Thanks, replaceAll("\\\\.?", ""); and it still didnt get rid of the A .  I'm still getting ###A instead of ###

Comment: @Slim'odaraProbably, because you replace in `raw`, but you must replace in `s`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/lUODh3).

Comment: @Edward: Works now! Thanks